$a/(a + 1)$ and $b/(b + 1)$ are given roots. Find quadratic with roots $a$ and $b$.

$a/(a+ 1)$ and $b/(b + 1)$ are the roots of $x^2 + 7x + 3 = 0$. Find a quadratic with roots $a$ and $b$.

In questions like this, I've been tediously simplifying them to equations just having $a + b$ and $a b$, and then putting values of them but that takes a lot of time, and I got to know transformation can be used in questions like this and I really want to know how it is done.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

The question shouldn't be in the title (and some of it is still missing), please consider editing your question so that the community can help you.

the title is itself the question and

The question for sure is complete and i will surely from next time put the question in body if you say i am new to stack exchange

As, $\frac{a}{a+1}$ is root of $x^2+7x+3=0$, we have
$$
(\frac{a}{a+1})^2+7\frac{a}{a+1}+3=0
$$
$$
\implies \frac{a^2+7a(a+1)+3(a+1)^2}{(a+1)^2}=0\implies a^2+7a^2+7a+3a^2+6a+3=0
$$
$$
\implies 11a^2+13a+3=0
$$
and so as the same approach can be followed for the root $\frac{b}{b+1}$, the required quadratic is $11x^2+13x+3=0$
PS:
As per the suggestion of @MarkBennet, I think this approach is simpler. Still, essentially the same, put $\frac{y}{y+1}=x$, as both $\frac{a}{a+1}$ and $\frac{b}{b+1}$ are roots of given quadratic, $a$,$b$ must satisfy the quadratic resulting from putting $\frac{y}{y+1}=x$, which is $11y^2+13y+3=0$.

Its trivial that following the same approach for the root $\frac{b}{b+1}$ would give the quadratic $11b^2+13b+3=0$, and so $11x^2+13x+3=0$ has roots $a$ and $b$, I think this is the transformation you were talking about.

Alternatively use $x=\frac {y}{y+1}$ and clear fractions, which is the same approach and gives an equation in $y$ once fractions are cleared.

So, a general approach would be to put the values of the root and simplify to get a quadratic, cubic etc.

@MarkBennet, Your approach is actually what I really meant but couldn't initially put that on this post, thanks for your valuable suggestion

We have
$$\frac{a}{a+1}+\frac{b}{b+1}=-7\implies\color{red}{8(a+b)+9ab=-7}\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{ab}{(a+1)(b+1)}=3\implies\color{red}{3(a+b)+2ab=-3}\tag{2}$$
$9\times\color{red}{(2)}-2\times\color{red}{(1)}$ gives
$$(27-16)(a+b)=-27+14=-13\implies\color{red}{ a+b=-\frac{13}{11},~ab=\frac{3}{11}}$$
So, the required quadratic is $\color {red}{11x^2+13x+3=0}$. $\blacksquare$

You say you want to do it by transformations. For quadratics it doesn't help much but if you'd been asked to do the same sort of thing for cubics, quartics, etc  then it definitely would help.
To do this one by transformations note that
$$\frac{a}{a+1}=
\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{a}}.
$$
Then we know that
$$
\frac{1}{1+\frac1a}, \frac{1}{1+\frac1b} \ \  \text{ are roots of }\ \  x^2+7x+3,
$$
so that
$$
1+\frac1a, 1+\frac1b \ \  \text{ are roots of }\ \  3x^2+7x+1,
$$
so that
$$
\frac1a, \frac1b \ \  \text{ are roots of }\ \  3(x+1)^2+7(x+1)+1=3x^2+13x+11,
$$
so that
$$
a,b \ \  \text{ are roots of }\ \ 11x^2+13x+3.
$$
